# Map from schemes to stacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles, grothendieck-topologies, algebraic-stacks

I have just started studying stacks. Trying to understand the theory I was thinking about a (very interesting) toy example: $ BG $ the classifying stack of a smooth (over a base scheme $ S $) group G. It is well known that a (smooth) cover is given by its canonical point $ s_0: S \rightarrow BG $ (the trivial torsor over $ S $ seen through Yoneda). Is it true that a map from a scheme $ X $ to $ BG $ factor through $ s_0 $?

In particular I had in mind the concrete example where $ S=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C) $ and where $ G=GL_n $ (so it is true that every torsor is locally trivial in the étale topology).

Comment: When $S=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$ and If $X\rightarrow BG$ factors through $s_0$, then I think the corresponding family is necessarily trivial

Comment: @loch: If you take $ X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C) $ as the structure morphism then you're certainly right. But I was thinking about something like an endomorphism of $ X $ composed with the structure morphism $ x:X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C) $ and then $s_0$. But I am not comfortable with stacks yet, so maybe I am making huge mistakes.

Comment: @loch: as stated by Sasha you were right, thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

No, a map $X \to BG$ is determined by a map $f:X \to S$ and a $f^*G$-torsor over $X$, while those map that factor through $s_0$ correspond to trivial torsors. So, as soon as there are nontrivial torsors over $X$, there are maps that do not factor through $s_0$.